# Use yield in for loop

Tags: c#

I have such function to read large txt files

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ReadLineFromFile(TextReader fileReader)
        {
            using (fileReader)
            {
                string currentLine;
                while ((currentLine = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    yield return currentLine;
                }
            }
        }
```

yield can be used only in foreach loop.

```
TextReader readFile = new StreamReader(file_path);
foreach (string url in ReadLineFromFile(readFile))
{
}
```

I need to re-write this function to use it with for loop. To state with Iterator the line to read.
I tried something but my attempts were unsuccessful
Any ideas?

Comment: I would use  [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) instead which is already implemented using deferred execution.

Comment: just curious, why you want to change from `foreach` to `for`?

Comment: as an aside you probably shouldnt dispose an onject passed in to your method as a parameter. Whoever creates an object should be responsible for disposing it afterwards.

Comment: Cuong Le I want to read lines multithreaded

Comment: @obdgy: Are you sure? It'll probably be slower...

Comment: It is not possible to read to different parts of a file independently from multiple threads if the file is a line-based text file. To know where the second line starts, you first need to know where the first line ends; to know where the third line starts, you first need to know where the second line ends; and so on. So if you have multiple threads, each thread would have to wait before the previous thread has finished. But then you have no advantage from using threads at all.

Answer (score 4):

The `yield` keyword can be used in *any* iterator block, not just `foreach` - your code should work.

<strike>The issue with your code is you are disposing of the `TextReader` after reading the first line.</strike>

Move the `using` statement outside the `ReadLineFromFile` method i.e.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file_path))
{
    foreach(string url in ReadLineFromFile(reader))
    {
        ...
    }
}

...
private static IEnumerable<string> ReadLineFromFile(TextReader fileReader)
{
    while ((var currentLine = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        yield return currentLine;
    }
}
```

---

I mistakenly *assumed* that using yield whilst having the enumerable code wrapped with a `using` would cause it to dispose early, however, I ran your code and it works fine!

Alternatively, if you fancy writing *less* code you could accomplish the same thing using [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file_path))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something in the question, but I don't understand why the `fileReader` object would be disposed before the end of the `while` loop

Comment: @KooKiz - Look at the OP code. `ReadLineFromFile` is called in a loop, but that method disposes of the very `TextReader` being used to read the file. You cant read the next line from a disposed `TextReader`.

Comment: @Jamiec It doesn't, since `ReadLineFromFile` uses the `yield return` instruction. The compiler rewrites the method as a state-machine and the dispose won't be called until the last item of the iteration. Try executing the code provided in the question, it works.

Comment: @KooKiz actually, you're right - I assumed it would dispose as the `using` get's called when the executing block of code is left (regardless if it's an enumerator), however, I just ran a test project with the OPs code and it ran fine...interesting!